# How do I inspect a Clojure map in GUI treeview from REPL like an IDE debugger would?

Tags: debugging, clojure

I want to debug a complicated nested map. It would be nice to quickly pop open a Swing TreeView that lets me navigate the map interactively, like any decent debugger in an IDE would. Is there an easy way to do this in Clojure?

Comment: What's wrong with just `pprint`ing your data structure?

Comment: That's like a tree view where you can't collapse anything. Sometimes it helps me to drill down into what I want to see and hide the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[clojure.inspector/inspect-tree](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.inspector-api.html#clojure.inspector/inspect-tree)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Cursive Clojure plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, you can set breakpoints and navigate your data structures interactively just like for any java app.